# Testing for parallel trends in panel data/diff-in-diff with only 4 time periods

Tags: regression, interpretation, stata, categorical-encoding

I am trying to test for common trends on Stata using *coefplot*, with 4 dummies for each time period (where they equal 1 at time *t* and if the individual is in the treatment group).

However, clearly one of the dummies will be omitted during a regression, so how is it possible to see if there's a common trend with only 3 dummy coefficients? Particularly, if common trends did not hold, how could I see whether there are differential trends which could be extracted using triple diff?